# Nvidia-settings won't work after attaching third GPU

Tags: ubuntu, nvidia, gpu

First I attached two GTX 1660 Super on my Z390 A Pro motherboard and installed Ubuntu 22.04. I successfully overclocked these GPUs using `nvidia-smi` and `nvidia-settings`.

But after attaching the third GPU (RTX 3060 TI) I can't use `nvidia-settings` anymore.

When I run the command `nvidia-smi` it returns:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 470.129.06   Driver Version: 470.129.06   CUDA Version: 11.4     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA GeForce ...  Off  | 00000000:02:00.0  On |                  N/A |
|  0%   47C    P8    16W / 125W |     25MiB /  5943MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   1  NVIDIA GeForce ...  Off  | 00000000:04:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| 30%   27C    P8    12W / 125W |      1MiB /  5944MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|  No running processes found                                                 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

But when I run the command `nvidia-settings` it returns:

```
(nvidia-settings:2926): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 21:37:24.306: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed

** (nvidia-settings:2926): CRITICAL **: 21:37:24.309: ctk_powermode_new: assertion '(ctrl_target != NULL) && (ctrl_target->h != NULL)' failed
** Message: 21:37:24.353: PRIME: No offloading required. Abort
** Message: 21:37:24.353: PRIME: is it supported? no
```

Comment: Looking at your situation, my research tells me that the motherboard referenced in your question (Z390 A Pro) only has 2x PCIe x16 connections yet you are attempting to use 3x PCIe x16 cards.  Does the RTX 3060 work when you remove one of the GTX 1660 cards and plug the RTX 3060 into a PCIe x16 socket?

Comment: Well turns out that the RTX 3060 TI needed 14 pins power cable instead of 8. I thought the extra 6 pins was for overclocking purposes..

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get multiple cards working in ubuntu 22.04 quite easy and be able to change settings with nvidia-settings, as oppose to same config on Fedora 33/34/35/36 where nvidia-smi works good with

```
nvidia-smi -pl 100
nvidia-smi -lgc 1050
```

but for mem clocks you need to use nvidia-settings.  What was you command with nvidia-settings?  I've used following (but on Fedora only first gpu is applied - gpu:0 others ignored)

```
nvidia-settings -c :0 -a [gpu:0]/GPUMemoryTransferRateOffsetAllPerformanceLevels=2200
nvidia-settings -c :0 -a [gpu:1]/GPUMemoryTransferRateOffsetAllPerformanceLevels=2200
...
```

However when changing configurations I always run

```
nvidia-xconfig -a --cool-bits=28 --allow-empty-initial-configuration --enable-all-gpus
```

to regenerate xorg.conf, and then starting GUI.  If you just run it remotely you can just run

```
startx
```

change values and then stop it.
Hope this gives you some clues.